# Typecasting Class Properties?

Tags: php

I am trying to typecast properties within my class, but they do not seem to work, granted I could put them inside my methods, but it'd be better/easier to change 1 property and inherit throughout the class, for example, I have tried the following:

```
/**
 * Return value as a string
 */
public string $string;

/**
 * Return value as integer
 */
private int $int;

/**
 * Return value as boolean
 */
private (boolean)$bool;

/**
 * Return value as
 */
private (float)$float;

/**
 * Return value as object
 */
private (object)$object;
```

Neither work, when I put them in () or not... Any reasons behind this?

Comment: _Any reasons behind this?_ Because this is not implemented in PHP.

Comment: Thanks... May I ask, is that good or a bad thing?

Comment: You may ask that if you are interested in people's opinions, but it won't change the fact.

Comment: You can [type hint in function definitions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration), and that's pretty much it.

Comment: You can write `__set` or `__get` methods that convert to the appropriate types automatically. It's not built into PHP, though.